# How to create single channel notification in MERN website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have made a website with MERN. Now I want to add single channel notification in it. It means if admin post something, user will get notification in notification section. Never done it before, so no idea.
If the admin posts something, I can easily show it in the notification section, but I am facing, the problem  is with the place where the notification bell icon has a dynamic counter. The notification bell counter/badge will actually show how many notifications are coming in the bell icon. If you click on the bell icon again, the counter will be zero.

How can I do this in MERN .[notification bell icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFQFG.png)

Comment: I guess you have some code to share.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Actually I have no Idea ,how to look forward .Because I never done this type of things before. I have just a concept. So I can't write any kind of code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to create communication channel which broadcast the server message to all the connected devices.

***Below is general overview:***

You have to create socket server in backend(express) and then emit the broadcast event from there.

```
io.emit('server message', { message: 'some value', otherProperty: 'other value' }); 
// This will emit the event to all connected sockets
```

You can write socket code for the client to listen to the event.

```
socket.on('server message', function(msg) {
// show the notification here
  });
```

Comment: Abhishek bhai, Do have any other option to create it? I mean any manual option without using any kind of library/packages . Example: An admin publish a post and an user find it in notification bell section. And bell icon counter/badge show the number of notification.When user click notification bell icon ,then all the notification number will be zero. Is it possible

Comment: @MdHridoyAhmmed It is not possible without some form of event listener. You have to somehow listen for an event to happen on the client/server to even show it in your 'notification bell section'. How else would there be a notification? socket.io is the way to go here.

Comment: yes, you can choose other message pushing services like firebase etc. and can use websocket if you don't want to use any library. But still you will need library for nodejs.